# JPA Exception saving parent/children

Tags: java, database, jpa

I am using JPA and have the following:

```
ProductEntity 

@Basic
@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false, length = 128)
private String productId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
private ProductEntity parent;
```

As you can see the product table can have a parent. Effectively a parent child relationship.

I have a product saved in the database, then I add some child products, each having the same parent.

- The parent Product has ProductEntity parent = null;
- The child Products have ProductEntity parent = the parent Product;

  ```
  ProductEntity parentProductEntity = ...
  ProductEntity childProductEntity1 = ...
  ProductEntity childProductEntity2 = ...

  em.persist(parentProductEntity);
  childProductEntity1.setParent(parentProductEntity);
  childProductEntity2.setParent(parentProductEntity);
  em.merge(childProductEntity1);
  ```

Data (it never inserts the last two child rows)

```
    ID        PRODUCT_ID     PARENT_ID
     1           1              null
     2           2                1
     3           3                1
```

**Problem**

I then try save each child Product. But I get an error indicating that there is a duplicate key (productId). When saving the child, it is trying to save a duplicate entry of the parent too.

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key
>   value violates unique constraint "t_osm_product_product_id_uindex"

**Question**

How must I change what I am doing to successfully save each child Product?

Thanks

Comment: can you show your code were you set the parent of the child product?

Comment: @RezaNasiri thanks, I have updated the explanation above.

Comment: it seems fine.what strategy you used to generate the primary key?

Comment: The table has a PK ID (auto increment) and a unique constraint PRODUCT_ID (which is generated by code, but always unique).

Comment: you need to annotate your PK with "@Id" not "@Basic"

Comment: Yea, looks like you are trying to emulate what's in the database but doing it incorrectly. There seems to be an index/constraint on product_id and your error message is there. Is that supposed to be the parent FK? If so, your entity is incorrect. Is it supposed to be a unique product_id for every entity? If so, are you setting it or leaving it null?

Comment: K.Nicholas thanks for the reply.  The PRODUCT_ID is never null and always unique.  When I try save the child, the parent productEntity's PRODUCT_ID is the same for each because of the @ManyToOne relationship.

Comment: Reza, the ID pk is not defined in the ProductEntity, is is just in the table.

Comment: Nobody can see what you are doing in your save code because you didn't post it so without that everyone is just guessing.

Comment: Without an `@Id` field, the EntityManager doesn't realise that you've already saved `parentProductEntity`, so attempts to save it again. That causes the duplicate key error. See @Reza Nasiri's answer below.

Comment: @Richard, is it possible to put your code into public repo? I think, some debugging required to solve this issue.

Comment: May I ask how you got this issue sorted out? It'd be beneficial to the community if you could share the outcome or accept some answer, if any helped you out.

Answer (score 2):

your entity should look like this

```
@Id
Long ID;

@Column(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false, length = 128)
private String productId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID")
private ProductEntity parent;
```

everything else seems fine in your code.

Data will look like this in the database

```
 ID        PRODUCT_ID     PARENT_ID
 1           abc              null
 2           def                1
 3           xyz                1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `@ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)`

Comment: Nope, unfortunately, I still get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Please change following point and check:-

- Use "persist" instead "merge" and do like following sequence.

{

```
public static void main (String[] agrs){
EntityManager em = ... // from EntityManagerFactory, injection, etc.

em.getTransaction().begin();

A parent   = new A();
A son      = new A();
A daughter = new A();

son.setParent(parent);
daughter.setParent(parent);

em.persist(parent);
em.persist(son);
em.persist(daughter);

em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Parkash.  I tried changing it so that it only does a 'persist' and not a 'merge', but now I get the following:  java.lang.IllegalStateException: During synchronization a new object was found through a relationship that was not marked cascade PERSIST: ProductEntity(productId=c0f3fd35-ed7e-48d1-8b3e-14cbb5a3a502).

Comment: please set "cascade=CascadeType.ALL" with @ManyToOne annotation and check.